# Processing: How can I make a game board with an array?

Tags: arrays, 2d, processing, sprite, 2d-games

*I need to make a game board - using an array - for a Bomberman game remake in Processing.*

This means the game board / array (which is rather large [9x9] and has 3 values [a,b,c] throughout), has to be able to:

- Define the color/sprite of the according fields
- Set the limit for where the character can walk
- Have unique properties for each value/field (one value represents the
  open space where the player can move around, another is a solid
  block, and another one breaks when a bomb is blown up next to it and
  transforms into an open field type)

I'm pretty much a programming noob and I barely a clue how to make all of this work..
I've already set up the array though which look like this:

```java
int [][] board =  { 
{b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b},  
{b, a, b, a, b, a, b, c, b}, 
{b, c, c, a, a, a, a, a, b},
{b, c, a, a, c, a, a, a, b}, 
{b, c, c, b, a, b, c, a, b}, 
{b, a, c, a, a, a, a, a, b}, 
{b, b, a, b, c, b, b, c, b}, 
{b, a, a, a, c, a, a, c, b}, 
{b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b}  };
```

And I have managed to draw it as a monochrome chessboard.
Now I just have to figure out how to give each value the properties of the according block type.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then approach each of those pieces one at a time.

For example, I'd start with a simple program that just draws a grid of squares. Then work your way up from there: can you make it so the number of squares is a variable (or two variables) that you define at the top of your sketch? Now make it so each square is a different color. Now make it so each square is reading from the array.

Work your way up in small pieces, and if you get stuck, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: That's what I did and I have a b&w grid with variables for rows and columns displaying, but I can't figure out how to color it right now.

Comment: @Unarmed What have you tried? Have you tried using an `if` statement to decide which color each square should be?

Comment: Yes but I  didn't manage.. I asked in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101117/processing-how-can-i-color-the-squares-drawn-by-my-2d-array-in-different-colors) question for that exact problem.

Answer (score -1):

Going off of what Kevin Workman said, here is code you could possibly use for a grid of squares:

```
void setup(){
  size(800, 800);
  background(255, 204, 5);
  fill(158, 10, 10);
  for(int i = width/8; i <= width; i += width/4){
     for(int v = height/8; v <= height; v += height/4){
        rect(i, v - height/8, width/8, height/8);
        rect(i - width/8, v, width/8, height/8);
     }
  }
}
```

It's not necessarily an array, but a for loop does the job.

Comment: Why do you need so many calls to `rect()` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Hold on, I think I can fix that.